# Yum install libyaml has depsolving problems

Tags: centos, yum, ruby

Trying to get ruby up and running on a centos 5 box.

```
yum install libyaml-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository updates is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository centosplus is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository contrib is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.symnds.com
 * base: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: mirror.umd.edu
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libyaml-devel.i386 0:0.1.2-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libyaml-0.so.1 for package: libyaml-devel
---> Package libyaml-devel.x86_64 0:0.1.4-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libyaml.i386 0:0.1.2-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libyaml-0.so.1()(64bit) for package: python26-PyYAML
---> Package libyaml.x86_64 0:0.1.4-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
python26-PyYAML-3.08-5.el5.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libyaml-0.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package python26-PyYAML-3.08-5.el5.x86_64 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libyaml-0.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package python26-PyYAML-3.08-5.el5.x86_64 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Scalr is installed on the machine and is managing things there, its the one that installed the python stuff

Comment: this is not a standard centos install if you have python26-YAML installed

Answer (score 2):

**NB: This answer is provided only for completeness; CentOS 5 is past end of life and rpmforge is a dead project. Neither should be used anymore.**

You previously installed `libyaml` from the third party repository "rpmforge", but then you disabled that repository. To install the corresponding `libyaml-devel` package, you need to re-enable that repository, either temporarily by using `--enablerepo=rpmforge` on the `yum` command line, or persistently by editing its repo file in the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory.

Answer (score -1):

In cases where I've had dependency issues with CentOS, I've used Fedora's EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux). If you go to the below link, you'll find packages for the EPEL. Download the appropriate RPM and them install it with rpm -ivh. Dependencies should resolve as normal. I will note that I cannot guarantee Fedora's packages for all cases of this, however, I've never personally had an issue using them in an enterprise environment.

[Link to EPEL Project](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)